# AlarmManager setInexactRepeating not working in Android 4.1.2, works on Android 4.3 and Above

Tags: android, scheduled-tasks, alarmmanager, scheduler

I am trying to create a repeating alarm manager call and I have found that for Android 4.1, 4.2 it does not get triggered the first time and I need to wait for the interval to see the process works:

```
public void startScheduler() {
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 100, // now
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, // Interval
            getSchedulerPendingIntent());

}
```

This only works when reached the AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES but not the "triggerAtMillis" argument. The thing is that this works on Android 4.4 and Android 5.0.

If I change the setInexactRepeating with setRepeating it work perfectly on Android 4.1 and 4.2, so:

```
public void startScheduler() {
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 100, // now
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, // Interval
            getSchedulerPendingIntent());

}
```

Works perfect for Android 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4 and 5.0. The only drawback is that for Android Api 19 and above it will work as an inexactRepeating and for android API 19 and below work as expected.

Is it make any relevant difference? I am missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Note: Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use.` as stated here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation for `setInexactRepeating()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29), specifically the `triggerAtMillis` parameter:

> time in milliseconds that the alarm should first go off, using the appropriate clock (depending on the alarm type). This is inexact: the alarm will not fire before this time, but there may be a delay of almost an entire alarm interval before the first invocation of the alarm.

IOW, this would appear to be working as expected.

Comment: I read that after posting my problem. The thing is... it works different in different API versions. I have to execute the task manually the first time, and that is kind of annoying when you have the chance to make it all with the AlarmManager. Anyway thanks for point this out!!